# How to put a $var in a DATE_ADD() from a BETWEEN situation, mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to select something where my column Heure is between $heure and $heure+5 min in mySQL.

```
SELECT * FROM `formulaires`.`ancienneadresse` WHERE Heure BETWEEN '$heure' AND DATE_ADD('$heure', INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

I tried the next one and it's working..

```
SELECT * FROM `formulaires`.`ancienneadresse` WHERE Heure BETWEEN '$heure' AND '15:46:55'
```

So, why am I wrong with DATE_ADD()?

Comment: Not a mysql/php guy, but just checking: are you using string interpolation here to put that data into your mysql query? If so, that's _really bad!_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your Heure field is set to varchar, so SQL is not understanding you're trying to compare time, you should try it like this:

```
 $heure_to=date("G:i:s", strtotime("$heure + 5 minutes"));
 SELECT * FROM `formulaires`.`ancienneadresse` WHERE 
 STR_TO_DATE(Heure, '%H:%i:%s') 
 BETWEEN '$heure' AND '$heure_to'
```

https://eval.in/131454

and here's a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cc810/5)

Comment: I used H:i:s instead of G:i:s and I removed STR_TO_DATE() and everything was fine :) Thanks you so much!